# stub method in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have 3 models :

```
Article:
has_many photos

Photo:
belongs_to article
belongs_to photoType

PhotoType:
has_many articles
```

And a factory :

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :article do
    title 'The Batcave'
    content '5 Smith Street'
    after_build do |article|
      article.photos << FactoryGirl.build(:photo, :article => article)
      article.photos << FactoryGirl.build(:photo, :article => article)
    end
  end
end
```

In article model i have a method get_photo(type) which query the databse a return one proper photo object based on type.

My question is how can i stub this method in my factory. Now get_photo always returns nil.

stubed article.get_photo(:big) should return article.photos[0]

Comment: do not do this. or dot his in an after(:stub)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok , i found a solution.

```
before(:all) do
    @articles = FactoryGirl.build_list(:article, 10)
end
```

And in test i have to add (I only need first article to test):

```
@articles[0].stub(:photo).with(:big).and_return(@articles[0].photos[1])
```

However When i put this line in before(:all) block it doesnt work . https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/279

Mocks are implicitly verified and cleared out after(:each) so they won't work in before(:all).